# ButtonPressed vs ButtonClicked

Tags: c#, events, user-interface

Is there any event naming convention regarding **ButtonPressed** and **ButtonClicked**? When should I use each of them? Or they should be considered synonyms?

Comment: What GUI are you talking about? WPF WinForms?

Comment: The events are pretty much identical between those platforms.
WPF goes an extra mile though, adding "previewMouseDown" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ButtonClicked fires when the mousebutton is pressed and subsequently released on the object.
ButtonPressed fires the second the mouse button is pressed on the object.

You could "cancel" your "click from firing" by pressing the mouse down on the object, but moving it away before releasing your mouse button

see :

[this DevExpress topic](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_ButtonPressedtopic)

Answer (score 1):

They are not synonyms.

ButtonPressed means that the button has been pressed, but not released, allowing you to capture the event DURING button pressing but before it is released.

ButtonClicked means that the button has been pressed and released

Answer (score 1):

ButtonPressed is more usual for when you are holding the mouse down on a button, or when it is a toggle button that can be on or off, whereas ButtonClicked is when you click and release the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to go with "pressed" - remember that you can press a button by highlighting it with the arrow keys and pressing Enter. If you want something specific to happen on a click, use `ButtonClicked`, otherwise use `ButtonPressed`. There's also the distinction of pressed vs pressed-and-released to consider.